# How do I use shorthands when using jest to mock nested objects

Tags: jestjs, mocking, window

```js
describe('test cli-request call', () => {
  it('api injection succeeded', () => {
    window.api = jest.fn();
    window.api.cli = jest.fn();
    window.api.cli.call = jest.fn();
    const mockCmdline = 'whatever';
    CLIRequest(mockCmdline);
    expect(window.api.cli.call).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
})
```

How should I write to be more concise, thanks.

Comment: `window.api = { cli: { call: jest.fn() } };`? You don't need mock functions all the way down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try later